# Filter dataframe with values repeated based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe, df_products, like this one:

| product_id | version | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | v1 | jan |
| 1111 | v2 | feb |
| 1111 | v2 | jan |
| 2222 | v1 | mar |
| 3333 | v2 | jan |
| 3333 | v2 | dec |
| 4444 | v1 | jun |
| 4444 | v1 | jan |
| 4444 | v2 | jun |

How can I filter it to get only the product_ids that have at least one v1 AND one v2 in the version column? I'd like to get something like this:

| product_id |
| --- |
| 1111 |
| 4444 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using set operations:

```
s = df.groupby('product_id')['version'].agg(set)

out = s[s >= {'v1', 'v2'}].index.tolist()
```

output:

```
[1111, 4444]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches:

One uses groupby and filter to remove groups that don't have both v1 and v2

```
df.groupby('product_id').filter(lambda x: all(v in x['version'].values for v in ['v1','v2']))['product_id'].unique().tolist()
```

Another idea would be to use a pivot table and dropna.

```
df.pivot_table(index='product_id', columns='version', values='month', aggfunc=set).dropna().index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create two additional columns `v1` and `v2` and mark 1 as present and 0 if not using

```
df['v1'] = 0
df.loc[df['version'] == 'v1', 'v1'] = 1

df['v2'] = 0
df.loc[df['version'] == 'v2', 'v2'] = 1
```

Then you can just use loc to generate the results that you need

```
result = df.loc[(df['v1'] == 1) & (df['v2'] == 1)]
```

Lastly, if you don't want the debug columns, drop them

```
df = df.drop(columns=['v1', 'v2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# values that should exist
v={'v1', 'v2'}

# group on product, and using transform aggregate the versions as set
# compare with the the valid list of version
# drop duplicates from the result
# return the product id

(df.loc[df.groupby(['product_id'] )['version']
        .transform(lambda x: set(x) == v )]
 .drop_duplicates(subset=['product_id'])['product_id'])
```

```
0    1111
6    4444
Name: product_id, dtype: int64
```